# Concatinating Column Values to a Single Row

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

For Example:

```
Color
_____
Green
Blue
```

output:

```
Green, Blue
```

(I'm using ms access 2007)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the mysql's group_concat equivalent in access

http://www.rogersaccesslibrary.com/forum/generic-function-to-concatenate-child-records_topic16.html

Comment: why does the text box output is "#Name?"

Comment: when you open it, a security warning appeared on top of the form, with an `Option` button, click on it and choose the `Enable this Content`

Comment: Help... i have another problem! :(  i have a table that has the 2 Columns "Applicant Number" and "Civil Service" I tried using this code in the concatentation for FirstNames Of Family Members "=Concatenate("SELECT FirstName FROM tblFamMem WHERE FamID =" & [FamID])" but it still doesn't work! its output is #Name? i tried Optien the Enable this Content but nothing changes...